# Lexical Analysis

Tags: c++, c, regex, visual-c++, compiler-construction

My target is to make a very simple and basic C syntax checker. (Not a full Compiler but just a basic Program which take a source code as Input and would print out the code back showing the errors). I want to use C++ as the language for this.

Can anyone guide me to write regular expression in 'c++' language for the following:

1. Assignment
2. For
3. switch

Any details/suggestions/guidance further would be much appreciated.

Comment: Note that lexical and syntactic analysis are very different things. Lexical analysis (scanning) divides your input in tokens, syntactic analysis (parsing) makes a syntax tree out of those tokens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can parse `C` with regular expressions alone. You'll need to start looking into lexers, parsers, grammars, etc...

A good starting point could be this: [Quick Starter on Parser Grammars - No Past Experience Required](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Quick+Starter+on+Parser+Grammars+-+No+Past+Experience+Required).

You can find `C` grammars online for `yacc`/`lex`.

Answer (score 3):

Checking the syntax of C code requires a lot more than regular expressions. You'll need a tool that supports parsing algebraic gammars instead, I'd suggest looking at [http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison) which will generate the "skeleton" of a parser in C++ so you can edit it and add your syntax-checking code.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `clang` libraries. A tutorial can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/loarabia/Clang-tutorial/wiki/TutorialOrig).

Answer (score 1):

Try [boost spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/page/2/)

Answer (score 0):

To recognize C statements, lexical analysis is not sufficient, because lexers work at the character level.  What you need, in addition to a C lexer, is a C parser which will do syntax analysis of the source code.  The [LRSTAR Parser Generator](http://lrstar.tech) supplies a C project which will get you up and running.

Comment: LRSTAR is at https://sourceforge.net/projects/lrstar/